# Centos find replace including spaces and $ in string

Tags: search, replace, centos, find

I need to recursively replace a string in some files but I cannot get it to work for my particular string(s).

If I use something simple like:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's,functions,functions2,g' {} \;
```

Then this works fine but if I use:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's#\$name = \$_POST\['name']#\$name2 = \$_POST\['name']#g' {} \;
```

then it does not work - I don't get any errors thrown and the file system shows that the file has changed in that the modified date changes but the actual string is not replaced.

Is there a special consideration for strings containing spaces, $ or '? I have tried / and \ to no avail

Comment: "Is there a special consideration ...?" No, not like what you're thinking. Your problem is probably related to either the fact that variables are not expanded inside single quotes, or that single quotes do not nest, but it's hard to tell without an example of an input and expected output, because it's not obvious whether you intend the variables to be expanded or not...

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out in the end - I used:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i -e "s@\$name = \$_POST\['name']@\$name2 = \$_POST\['name']@g" '{}' \;
```

The $ and [ needed to be escaped and changing to the @ as the delimiter from , in my case made it work.

I always thought as long as the delimiter was not in your string to find or replace then anything could be used but then I read that @ has some special meaning though I cannot find the SO article I read it on right now.